# Change the width of a UIView that already exists in Storyboard? Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uiview

I already have created a UIView in the storyboard and connected it as an outlet, with the name `progressView`
In Swift, I want to be able to change the width of this view in a certain function, however, so far I have been unable to.

I would really appreciate any help.

Comment: try to change -> progressView.fram.size.width

Comment: I've tried doing that, but it doesn't seem to work

Comment: if the project is autolayout try to change progressView.width.constant

Comment: That comes up with the error: 'Value of type UIView has no member 'width'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've just write an example , if your project is autolayout ,  you need to define width constraint for progressView , then you need to make an outlet connection from your constraint and then change this property at method

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet NSLayoutConstraint *ViewWidth;
```

in method:

```
 self.ViewWidth.constant =number;
```

Comment: Thank! That worked. I converted the Obj-C into Swift:

`@IBOutlet weak var progressViewWidth: NSLayoutConstraint!`

and then: 

        `self.progressViewWidth.constant = 50`